# IO Exception using java-google-translate-text-to-speech Api

Tags: java

I am having issues using java-google-translate-text-to-speech.Trying to translate a language to another. This is my code:

```
import com.gtranslate.Language;
import com.gtranslate.Translator;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args){
               Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
               String text = translate.translate("Hello", Language.ENGLISH,Language.PORTUGUESE);
               System.out.println(text); 
              }
          }
```

Its giving me an error:

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t%3Fclient%3Dt%26text%3DHello%26hl%3Den%26sl%3Den%26tl%3Den%26multires%3D1%26prev%3Dbtn%26ssel%3D0%26tsel%3D0%26sc%3D1&q=CGMSBHqsFhAY_L3FqQUiGQDxp4NLxnAO-gsMAyd56ktUpufqNjEC280

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1459)
at com.gtranslate.utils.WebUtils.source(WebUtils.java:24)
at com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate.parse(ParseTextTranslate.java:19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found a simple 2-step solution. Please see Comment #4 at the following URL (requires only a minor modification of the sources):

https://code.google.com/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/issues/detail?id=8

**STEP 1** in Comment #4 is straightforward. Let me cite it from the above webpage:

*In class com.gtranslate.URLCONSTANT change public static final String GOOGLE_TRANSLATE_TEXT = "http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?";*

TO public static final String GOOGLE_TRANSLATE_TEXT1 = "http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/single?";

...however in **STEP 2** it is much simpler just to add a `&dt=t` URL parameter-value pair at the end of the generated URL in the `com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate.appendURL()` method.

...the original STEP 2 in Comment #4 above was the following, I cite (FYR):

STEP2) In the class, the appendURL function needs to be changed as shown com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate @Override public void appendURL() { Text input = textTranslate.getInput(); Text output = textTranslate.getOutput(); url = new StringBuilder(URLCONSTANTS.GOOGLE_TRANSLATE_TEXT); /* url.append("client=t&text=" + input.getText().replace(" ", "%20")); url.append("&hl=" + input.getLanguage()); url.append("&sl=" + input.getLanguage()); url.append("&tl=" + output.getLanguage()); url.append("&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1"); */

```
        url = new StringBuilder(URLCONSTANTS.GOOGLE_TRANSLATE_TEXT); 

url.append("client=t&sl=auto&tl="+ output.getLanguage()
                +"&hl=" + input.getLanguage()
                +"&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qc&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=1&rom=1&ssel=0&tsel=3&kc=1&tk=620730|996163"
                + "&q=" + input.getText().replace(" ", "%20"));
```

}

**.........end of citation**...and sooooooooo, for example, just replace this line in the `appendURL()` method:

```
url.append("&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1");
```

...to this:

```
url.append("&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1&dt=t");
```

**Additionally** here are some values for the `dt` URL param, which practically specifies what to return in the reply:

- **t** - translation of source text
- **at** - alternate translations
- **rm** - transcription / transliteration of source and translated texts
- **bd** - dictionary, in case source text is one word (you get translations with articles, reverse translations, etc.)
- **md** - definitions of source text, if it's one word
- **ss** - synonyms of source text, if it's one word
- **ex** - examples
- ...

P.S.: A similar HTTP 503 error happens with Google TTS (due to the background API change). You can find the solution to that problem here: [Text to Speech 503 and Captcha Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794033/text-to-speech-503-and-captcha-now)

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP Response Code: 503** : Service Unavailable says : The server is currently unavailable may be because it is overloaded or down for maintenance.

The server  might currently be unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.

Note: Some servers may simply refuse the connection and might result in 503 response