# Text to Speech 503 and Captcha Now

Tags: text-to-speech, google-translate

I've been using the Google Text to Speech engine for quite some time and today I've started receiving 503s and captcha requests.  My original query was

https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hi

Assuming I needed an API Key, I requested a key and added that to the URL query string

https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&key=xxxxxxx&q=hi

However, my service is still receiving the captcha request.  I'm assuming that the API has been changed but can't find any documentation to support this.

Anyone else running into this issue?

Comment: To follow up on this issue... 

I eventually switched to using a voice from CereProc and crafted a service in C# for our needs.  It took a bit more time to put together but in the end I had more flexibility and no worries of it being offline.

https://www.cereproc.com/en/products/sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API for TTS from Google.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/1-8d2JkGwDE

I run into this same problem with captcha.

Answer (score 4):

The straightforward fix with adding query &ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&client=t is also down now! Google has a very strict policy to protect automatic queries. I am also looking for a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

try this one. it worked for me!

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello&ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&client=t

update: still works with wget.

wget -q -U Mozilla "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello&ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&client=t"

Comment: Cool, this one seems to work without captcha, ... for now.

Comment: hello  Ruchira, please can you explain me what client=t stand for and what are the other option for client parameter.  Thank

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and switched to using Voice RSS http://www.voicerss.org/

Voice RSS does not support as many languages as Google TTS but I had to use something and the Voice RSS is good.

Answer (score 0):

There is paid version of Goggle Translate API https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq

Still would like to see a workaround for a call that is made from google.translate.com. Looks like the main issue is "tk" query string parameter.